# What this piece of code does and where it is used

Tags: c, algorithm, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

There is such snippet of asm code from Denis Yurichev's Reverse Engineering challenge #10
https://challenges.re/10/

> Optimizing GCC 4.8.2:
>
> This code snippet is short, but tricky. What does it do? It's used
> heavily in low-level programming and is well-known to many low-level
> programmers. There are several ways to calculate it, and this is the
> one of them.
>
> ```
> f:
> lea eax, [rdi-1+rsi]
> neg esi
> and eax, esi
> ret
> ```

In C, this piece of code looks something like this:

```
(a+b-1) & (-b)
```

Please help me figure out what this snippet of code does and where it is used

I ran several test values for a and b, I did not see a pattern

Comment: Hint: have you tried with `b` being a power-of-2?

Comment: Until your answer, I had not tried setting the b to a power of two. Tried it now, it really is as you say. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Peter Cordes hints in a comment, the expression `(a+b-1) & (-b)` is probably only useful when `b` is a power of two.  In this case the result is `a` rounded up to a multiple of `b`.

For example with a=33 and b=32, the result is 64.

Such an expression may be useful in memory allocation or alignment calculations (the C standard specifies that alignment is a power of two for every type).

Comment: And this works because, for a power of two, `-b` yields a pattern with all bits at the position of the sole 1 bit in `b` and higher set to 1, so the `&` keeps only those bits from `a+b-1`, setting the low bits to zero. If `a` is a multiple of `b`, those high bits of `a+b-1` are the same as `a`, so the result is `a`. Otherwise, those high bits are the high bits of the next multiple of `b` after `a`, so the result is that next multiple.